# Apply easyxf style for specific cell or row range only: xlwt Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I written few lines code..

```
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet('Section details', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
style_detail = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Calibri, height 180,colour_index black;align: wrap on, vert center, horiz center; border : bottom thin,right thin,top thin,left thin;')
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 0, 0, 'Product Family')
sheet.write_merge(1, 1, 0, 0, 'Product Category')
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 1, 1, 'Product')
.
.
sheet.write_merge(n, n, n, n, 'Product') //n is just dynamic number..
```

Now, After completing all my writing work. Want to apply style for specific cells only(depending on requirement).

```
rw = sheet.row(1)
rw.set_style(style_detail)
```

If i apply style for specific row then it apply for entire row of sheet(for column A to endless columns). How can i apply style for specific cell of any row only?

Please let us know if any more code or info require to get idea.

Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the style object as the 6th argument of the write_merge() function as

```
    sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 0, 0, 'Product Family',style_detail)
```

and when you want to have default style, ignore the 6th argument.